# top of webpage shows git head pointing to origin/master

Tags: git, github

I have to git branches for my project

**master**

**production**

I made some pretty big mess in my master branch so to solve the mess I used the

```
git rebase origin/production
```

Now everything is working fine but I have this message on top of my page

```
<<<<<<< HEAD ======= >>>>>>> origin/master
```

I tried making a temporary branch **temp**
using `git checkout -b temp`
then updated master to point at it using `git checkout -B master temp`
finally deleted the branch using `git branch -d temp`

still no luck

How do I get rid of the message on top of the page?

Picture for reference
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means there was a merge conflict (can happen when merging or rebasing). The rebase is not finished yet. Your command line should have told you that there were conflicts. I can not tell you how to fix the conflict as this is too specific to your concrete situation. If you have not idea what a merge conflict is, you should start by reading up on this topic (e.g. [Resolving Merge Conflicts Using The Command Line](https://docs.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-issues-and-pull-requests/resolving-a-merge-conflict-using-the-command-line)).

Comment: I read the article you provided but when I type in git status(as suggested by the article) I should get a log of the conflicts
But all I get is **Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master**'

Comment: This means that you "accepted" the conflict by doing `add` and `commit` after the rebase. I wouldn't know of any other way this could have happened. The text that you see in your webpage is a conflict marker in your HTML page or your template or whatever you use to generate the page.

Comment: yes the text was from index.html file inside public directory, which I usually overlook
thanks